# How to check IF getOrigData() has changed using Observer?

Tags: event-observer, customer-address, data

I am using `customer_address_save_after` event to check do stuff when a customer address has been changed/edited.

I need to somehow prevent the execution of my code if the address hasn't changed. This is because the `customer_address_save_after` event fires on save customer which might mean the address hasn't been changed but a different customer config setting.

Here is what I have tried so far:

I set the `$address` variable with `getData()` and `$orig_address` with `getOrigData()`

I then want to check if the data has changed since the last save

```
if($address != $orig_address && $orig_address['updated_at'] < $address['updated_at']){

      Do stuff...

 }
```

I have done some searching and seen that there is a `_hasDataChanges()` method but I've never used it and cannot find any examples of it's use...

Any suggestions are welcomed

**UPDATE**

I've accessed the `_hasDataChanges()` method which is always going to be true if the save event fires due to the `updated_at` customer attribute.
I need to find a way to exclude that part of the data from the check...

Answer (score 4):

Before the after load events are dispatched, `_origData` and therefore `_hasDataChanges` are reset.

What you can do: Make your checks in an observer for `customer_address_save_before`, set a flag in your observer singleton, and check for that flag in `customer_address_save_after`:

```
public function checkAddressOnSaveBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    if ($observer->getModel()->hasDataChanges()) {
        $this->addressHasChanged = true;
    }
}

public function doStuffOnSaveAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    if ($this->addressHasChanged) {
        do_stuff();
        $this->addressHasChanged = false;
    }
}
```

The `updated_at` attribute is automatically set *during save*, so it should not influence the results in the first observer method.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, from what I can see the `hasDataChanges()` method will always be true even if the `customer_address_save_before` method is called instead of `customer_address_save_after` This is because the `updated_at` value is changed as soon as `save` is dispatched.

Comment: No, `updated_at` is set in the attribute backend model, triggered by `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract::_beforeSave()`. This happens *after* `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::_beforeSave()`.

Comment: Why would `hasDataChanges()` be set to `true` if there are no data changes? The only data the has changed is the `updated_at` or am I missing the point?